# discrete Guassian model in fortran 90

Tags: fortran90

I want to generate discrete random numbers (for 1000 ensemble) with Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance 2.25. I saw in the book [NUMERICAL RECIPES in Fortran  90](http://apps.nrbook.com/fortran/index.html), chapter 7, section 7.2, the function `gasdev` used for this, but I don't know how to use this function.

How can I use the number of ensembles and mean and variance?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

IMO, how to use a function from NR is best written in NR itself.

If you need to generate normally distributed real numbers, google for "Box-Muller transform", or go directly to the [Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) and/or dozens questions and answers here on SO.

If your requirement is to generate *integers* (did you mean that by asking about *discrete random numbers*?), I'd say the easiest way [is to compute the cdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373192/generating-discrete-random-variables-with-various-weights-using-scipy-or-numpy/11374850#11374850).

Comment: I want to generate discrete random numbers (for 1000 ensemble) with Gaussian distribution with mean zero and variance 2.25. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`gasdev` returns normally distributed random variable with mean of `0.0` and variance of `1.0`, often written as `N(0, 1)`. You should scale the result with the variance in order to match the desired distribution. Note that if `x` is `N(0, 1)` (as returned by `gasdev`), then `y = a + b*x` is `N(a, b^2)`, i.e. normally distributed random variable with mean of `a` and variance of `b^2`.

(btw, if this is a homework, it should be properly tagged as such)

Comment: By the way, This is NOT homework. I am a PhD student in biology and I need this for modeling cell populations.For 1000 ensemble, I was wondering where to put this number in the gasdev function?

Comment: what is idum in the gasdev function?

Comment: It's the seed for the pseudorandom number generator used by `gasdev`. You should pass some negative value on the first call to `gasdev` and then further just pass `0`.

Comment: You mean I have to define seed=-1 , gasdev(seed)?