# Running into "NameError" and "TypeError" in Python

Tags: python

I am running into an error of "NameError" with the following code (from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14659965/3284469):

```
>>> import scipy
>>> import numpy
>>> values = [10, 20, 30]
>>> probabilities = [0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
>>> distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'rv_discrete' is not defined
```

Could you give me some solution or hint to solve the problem? Thanks!

---

Updated: Following the solution by mhlester, I solved the Name error, but bump into type error:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
>>> distrib = scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 4903, in __init__
    if name[0] in ['aeiouAEIOU']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to give it the full namespace:

```
import scipy
...
scipy.stats.rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
```

Or import it directly:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
...
rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
```

Comment: Thanks! +1.  I now bump into a new TypeError, and I updated my post with this new one.

Comment: The error is because `name` is `None`. I've never used `scipy` myself so you'll have to turn to someone else for further answer inside `distributions`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like some time has passed, but I was getting the same error as you. It seems that you have to specify the "name" variable here for some reason. For instance, for me the following worked:

```
from scipy.stats import rv_discrete
values = (10, 20, 30)
probabilities = (0.2, 0.5, 0.3)
distrib = rv_discrete(name='my_special_discrete_simulator', values=(values, probabilities))
distrib.rvs(size=10)
array([20, 20, 20, 30, 20, 20, 30, 20, 10, 30])
```

but replacing the 4th line with:

```
distrib = rv_discrete(values=(values, probabilities))
```

Gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/stats/distributions.py", line 4903, in __init__
  if name[0] in ['aeiouAEIOU']:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```