# Random words generate using python

Tags: python-2.7, random

I have a list of words

```
count=100    
list = ['apple','orange','mango']
```

for the count above using random function is it possible to select 40% of the time apple, 30% of the time orange and 30% of the time mango?

for ex:

```
for the count=100, 40 times apple, 30 times orange and 30 times mango.
```

this select has to happen randomly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on an answer to the question about [generating discrete random variables with specified weights](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32179721/1916449), you can use [`numpy.random.choice`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to get 20 times faster code than with `random.choice`:

```
from numpy.random import choice

sample = choice(['apple','orange','mango'], p=[0.4, 0.3, 0.3], size=1000000)

from collections import Counter
print(Counter(sample))
```

Outputs:

```
Counter({'apple': 399778, 'orange': 300317, 'mango': 299905})
```

Not to mention that it is actually easier than "to build a list in the required proportions and then shuffle it".

Also, shuffle would always produce *exactly* 40% apples, 30% orange and 30% mango, which is not the same as saying "produce a sample of million fruits according to a discrete probability distribution". The latter is what both `choice` solutions do (and the `bisect` too). As can be seen above, there is *about* 40% apples, etc., when using `numpy`.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to build a list in the required proportions and then shuffle it.

```
>>> import random
>>> result = ['apple'] * 40 + ['orange'] * 30 + ['mango'] * 30
>>> random.shuffle(result)
```

Edit for the new requirement that the count is really 1,000,000:

```
>>> count = 1000000
>>> pool = ['apple'] * 4 + ['orange'] * 3 + ['mango'] * 3
>>> for i in xrange(count):
        print random.choice(pool)
```

A slower but more general alternative approach is to [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html#module-bisect) a [cumulative probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function):

```
>>> import bisect
>>> choices = ['apple', 'orange', 'mango']
>>> cum_prob_dist = [0.4, 0.7]
>>> for i in xrange(count):
        print choices[bisect.bisect(cum_prob_dist, random.random())]
```

Comment: But if the count=1000000 then the list size will increase right, actually I'm trying to simulate a data set like 1000000 rows per day over a period of one month, would it be good if i use the same logic?

Comment: The concept is perfectly general and there are many ways to build on it.  I editted the answer to show how to use random.choice() to make one selection at a time from of pool where the elements are in proper proportion.  You could also make a cumulative distribution and use *bisect* for the selection but that would have been overkill for the way you described your problem.