# How do I fix this for yelp/python scraping?

Tags: python, yelp

this is my assignment

Scrape at least 400 full reviews and ratings from Yelp for a restaurant that has mixed reviews.
Recode the ratings. 1-3 = Negative, 4-5 = Positive.
Clean and pre-process the data (remove punctuation, remove stopwords, convert all words to lower case).
Split the data 70/30 and develop a naïve Bayes, decision tree and logistic regression models (10 pts.)
Report recall, precision, F1, accuracy and AUC for each model (5 pts.)
Select the best metric for comparing model and explain your rationale. Identify the best model

I put this code in:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import recall_score, precision_score, f1_score, accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import auc

nb = GaussianNB()

nb.fit(X_train_feats, y_train)

y_pred_nb = nb.predict(X_test_feats)
y_pred_nb_prob = nb.predict_proba(X_test_feats)[:, 1]

fpr_nb, tpr_nb, _ = roc_curve(y_test, y_pred_nb_prob)
roc_auc_nb = auc(fpr_nb, tpr_nb)
```

I am getting an error : index 1 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Index Error: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665398/index-error-index-3-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-1-with-size-3)

Comment: I'm not sure, I am new to python and not good with it. I need someone to comment on how to specifically change the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change [:, 1] to [:, 0] should work, but it depends on which line you are getting the error from.