# What is the issue with my last dense keras layer?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, multiclass-classification

I am working on a small NN in keras for multi-class classification problem. I have 9 different labels and my features are also 9.

My train/test shapes are the following:

```
Sets shape:
x_train shape: (7079, 9)
y_train shape: (7079,)
x_test shape: (7079, 9)
y_test shape: (7079,)
```

But when I try to make them categorical:

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=9)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes=9)
```

I get the following error:

```
IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 9
```

Here is more info about the `y_train`

```
print(np.unique(y_train)) # [1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
print(len(np.unique(y_train))) # 9
```

Anyone would know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape of the `y_train` is `1D`. You have to make it **one-hot** encoded. Something like

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train , num_classes=9)
```

And same goes for `y_test` too.

#### Update

According to the [doc](https://keras.io/api/utils/python_utils/#to_categorical-function),

```
tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None, dtype="float32")
```

Here, **y**: class vector to be converted into a matrix (integers from `0` to `num_classes`). As in your case, `y_train` is something like `[1,2,..]`. You need to do as follows:

```
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train - 1, num_classes=9)
```

---

Here is an example for reference. If we do

```
class_vector = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 4, 2])
print(class_vector)

output_matrix = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(class_vector, 
                                      num_classes = 5, dtype ="float32")
print(output_matrix)
```

```
[1 1 2 3 5 1 4 2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-69c8be7a0f1a> in <module>()
      6 print(class_vector)
      7 
----> 8 output_matrix = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(class_vector, num_classes = 5, dtype ="float32")
      9 print(output_matrix)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/np_utils.py in to_categorical(y, num_classes, dtype)
     76   n = y.shape[0]
     77   categorical = np.zeros((n, num_classes), dtype=dtype)
---> 78   categorical[np.arange(n), y] = 1
     79   output_shape = input_shape + (num_classes,)
     80   categorical = np.reshape(categorical, output_shape)

IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 5
```

To solve this, we convert the data to a zero-based format.

```
output_matrix = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(class_vector - 1, 
                                     num_classes = 5, dtype ="float32")
print(output_matrix)

[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: let me know if it works for you or not. It should though.

Comment: It's now complaining again: IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 9

Comment: Can you add some information about your `x_train` and `y_trian`?

Comment: `TRAIN - Dataset No. of Rows:  7079
TRAIN - Dataset No. of Columns:  10
TEST - Dataset No. of Rows:  7079
TEST - Dataset No. of Columns:  10`

Of those 10 columns, the very first one is the target and the rest the features.

x_train shape: (7079, 9)
y_train shape: (7079,)

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Would you please check this answer, and ensure that it's not happening to your case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41666051/9215780

Comment: Not really... I just did `print(np.unique(y_train))` and it returned `[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]` and `print(len(np.unique(y_train)))` and returned 9.

Comment: Ok, please update your question with the latest traceback. It would be much clear.

Comment: It should be `num_classes=9 ` not 10.

Comment: Just updated it. 9 is still throwing the same error.

Comment: Can you try this `..to_categorical(y_train - 1, num_classes=9)`