# IndexError: index 24 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've written a code to make feature extraction on large datasets with Deep Learning using Keras.

I followed this tutorial (I used the same code):
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/05/27/keras-feature-extraction-on-large-datasets-with-deep-learning/

But I changed the dataset: my dataset contains 105 classes **(Face recognition dataset)**.

**Train:** 15224 images

**Test:** 1155 images

**Validation:** 1155 images

But when I want to train the model I get this error: **IndexError: index 24 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2**

Comment: check the shape of your inputs, i don't think it is as large as you are expecting

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've changed the input shape to input_shape=(7 * 7 * 50000,). But I got this error: IndexError: index 90 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Comment: Did you check the answers of  this similar SO issue.     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41665398/index-error-index-3-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-1-with-size-3