# Generate Random numbers with probability

Tags: python, random, probability

I was wondering how I could generate a list of random number (1, 2) but with different probability. 
ie : 1 has a probability of 0.6 and 2 has a probability of 0.4.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373192/5351549

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a duplicate of some question, but since that other question specifically asks for a scipy/numpy solution, I don't see how it could count as a duplicate (especially since scipy/numpy are overkill for this.)

Comment: Perfect example of how the dup flag is abused on SO.

Comment: `random.choices` will do it, but if using a library function isn't allowed, `random.choice([j for i in range(len(nums)) for j in [i] * int(10 * probabilities[i])])` works, assuming the numbers are unique to begin with

Answer (score -3):

Use `random.choice`

```
import random
random.choice([1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2])
```

You can also write

```
data = [1]*6 + [2]*4
choice = random.choice(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if we have a probability of 0.53251?

Comment: Can anyone tell me the reason for down vote?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz This method only works for the most simplistic of cases. The asker asked a question that would be difficult to achieve with your solution.

Comment: @SethM.Larson Read question again. Exact same question was asked that I answered. choose 1 with probability 0.6 and 2 with 0.4.

Comment: Read what OP posted as a comment to your answer. In case you missed it: `Thanks for the reply. But what if we have a probability of 0.53251?`

Comment: But that was not asked @SethM.Larson

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I agree the question is bad. It states a simple case, and then OP asks for probability of Pi/sqrt(45)

Comment: I don't think that it is fair for someone to penalize you for answering the original question (instead of one that popped up in the comments), although it is still a valid criticism of your answer that it isn't very flexible. There are more flexible versions which are just as easy to write (e.g. `1 if random.random() < 0.6 else 2`.)